# Getting error in JSON response in afnetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have to make a post request to my server which takes JSOn . I am using following code to make a request:

```
    AFHTTPClient* httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:SERVER_URL]];

     [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *jsonRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/"                    parameters:@{@"name":@"piggy"}];


    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation2 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:jsonRequest     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {


     NSLog(@"RECEIVED: %@  ", JSON);

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    //NSLog(@"GGG:%@",JSON);
}];
```

But I am getting error:

2013-04-11 11:07:40.089 Connect

```
 Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0xad8c6e0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains it: You are expecting a JSON response but the actual response is HTML. Its either 1) You have a wrong URL or 2) You are not handling the request properly.

Comment: may be problem with request? but what problem?

Comment: What i meant was you may have a problem in your server. You may not be handling the request properly so instead of responding with a JSON, your server response is HTML.

Comment: What is your expected response from your server? Is it supposed to respond with JSON data?